# Question about Entity Framework: is ID considered a key value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does EF automatically assign IDs when adding an object to the database?

ex: when I was testing it, I didn't know how it worked and ran the code that adds a couple of objects to the DB a couple of times, but when checking it, I found that all the IDs were increased by one perfectly, even when I set the value manually

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new AulaContext())
        {
            var a = new Aula();
            var b = new Aula();
            var c = new Aula();
            var d = new Aula();
            var e = new Aula();
            var f = new Aula();
            var g = new Aula();
            var h = new Aula();

            a.Id = 0;
            a.Capacidad = 30;
            a.ConexionARed = true;
            a.Proyeccion = true;
            a.Aul = "1.1";
            b.Id = 0;
            b.Capacidad = 30;
            b.ConexionARed = true;
            b.Proyeccion = true;
            b.Aul = "1.2";
            c.Id = 0;
            c.Capacidad = 30;
            c.ConexionARed = true;
            c.Proyeccion = true;
            c.Aul = "1.3";
            d.Id = 0;
            d.Capacidad = 30;
            d.ConexionARed = true;
            d.Proyeccion = true;
            d.Aul = "2.1";
            e.Id = 0;
            e.Capacidad = 30;
            e.ConexionARed = true;
            e.Proyeccion = true;
            e.Aul = "2.2";
            f.Id = 0;
            f.Capacidad = 30;
            f.ConexionARed = true;
            f.Proyeccion = true;
            f.Aul = "2.3";
            g.Id = 0;
            g.Capacidad = 30;
            g.ConexionARed = true;
            g.Proyeccion = true;
            g.Aul = "1.4";
            h.Id = 0;
            h.Capacidad = 30;
            h.ConexionARed = true;
            h.Proyeccion = true;
            h.Aul = "1.5";

            db.Aulas.Add(a);
            db.Aulas.Add(b);
            db.Aulas.Add(c);
            db.Aulas.Add(d);
            db.Aulas.Add(e);
            db.Aulas.Add(f);
            db.Aulas.Add(g);
            db.Aulas.Add(h);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var query = from aul in db.Aulas
                        orderby aul.Id
                        select aul;
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


}

public class Aula
{
    private int id;
    public int Id { get {return id;} set { id = value; } }

    private int capacidad;
    public int Capacidad { get { return capacidad; } set { capacidad = value; } }

    private bool conexionARed;
    public bool ConexionARed { get { return conexionARed; } set { conexionARed = value; } }

    private bool proyeccion;
    public bool Proyeccion { get { return proyeccion; } set { proyeccion = value; } }

    private string aul;
    public string Aul { get { return aul; } set { aul = value; } }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ID: " + this.id + "\n" +
                "Capacidad: " + this.capacidad + "\n" +
                "Conexion a red: " + this.conexionARed + "\n" +
                "Proyector: " + this.proyeccion + "\n" +
                "Aula: " + this.aul;

    }
}

public class AulaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Aula> Aulas { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Depends how you mapped it? Show your mapping code

Comment: Alright, I edited the post.

Comment: I mean the code that tells EF which table and columns to map to your local object - see something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties - ever written anything like this?

Comment: I don't really know, I just followed a tutorial on microsoft docs

Comment: Linking us to the tutorial will help us determine more about your setup

Comment: The "issue" you described is slightly related to the PK assignment, but not entirely. Based off conventions, the default convention is: A property called "Id" or "[ClassName]Id" is used as the PK of the mapped to table, and is used as an identity column. This means that not only these properties in the table have to be unique and will be used as an identification for the row in update/delete statements, but also that EF won't pass its value in insert statements because the DB will generate a new value for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF will automatically choose the Id field as a primary key, it could have chosen AulaID as a primary key in the absence of Id field. That is the Convention over configuration.

You can however change that behavior by marking some other field as the Primary Key of the Table in the POCO class or in the EF configurations.
In the absence of an explicit command, EF will use conventions to determine the primary key.